# What about store data into shared object?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

Eg I have some data which my program needs to load it. and I want to load it fast.

I thinking there have 3 ways to load it.

1. Write the data into JSON or XML and parse the data.
2. Serialize the data into certain binary format and unserialize it.
3. Write the data into c file and compile it store the data into `.so`, load the shared object using `dlopen`.

Is the 3rd way a good idea?
Or What is the fast way to load persistent data?

**Background info:**

> Where do the data come from?

The user who uses the program create the data.
Could consider the data as config, the program is fixed but the data is flexible.

> Does your program only read the data?

No, the program uses it, process it and maybe show it...

> How often will you change the data?

Basically once, but I think that doesn't matter. I just want it to load fast every time during the program running.

> Will you prepare the data on the same machine where your program is
>   running?

No, the target machine is very very slow...in my case using cross-compiler(ARM).

**More bg info:**

I have a very low spec ARM board and want my program to load the config data as fast as possible. So I think to move the time of parsing to the data preparation phase. I don't care about the portability or complexity. Only need **speed**.

Comment: I do not see the advantage of point 3 as opposed to simply memory-map a binary file with the data.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add more background information. I guess you want to change the data without modifying your program. Where do the data come from? Does your program only read the data? How often will you change the data? Will you prepare the data on the same machine where your program is running? Reading the file is the slowest operation compared to any processing, so you might not notice a big difference between binary and text formats.

Comment: All three methods work.  All involve reading a file at runtime.  A shared object is probably hardest (assuming you already have an XML or JSON library in your program).  It is the least flexible.  It is aconventional to use a shared object for the purpose.  Don't forget the "simple" text file format, or variations such as YAML.

Comment: @Bodo I add the background information.

Comment: "Where do the data come from? The user who uses the program." doesn't help much. Please describe the use case in more detail. If the data will be entered only once, why don't you put it into your program code? If you want to prepare the data on a different machine, you should use a portable data format because binary data might not be compatible between different systems/processors/compilers.

Comment: Does your target device support dynamic linking? Why would you use `dlopen`, can't the linker take it? You could just `struct userdata_s *userdata = mmap(file)` or just link with a library that has `struct userdata_s *get_userdata()` symbol exposed.

Comment: The third method is less handling. Each time you'll need to modify the values of data you shall re-compile the library. If you use the library in more programs you'need to pay attention at the use all your programs make of the data in the library (if you think to use the same library in more programs). I think that  the better way  to have fast data access is to load them when the program starts thus they may be easily used inside it.

Comment: Has the data to be separated from the program which reads it ? Is it text data or binary data ? Does the data involves pointers ? Any way if you can avoid parsing xml, json, yaml or any other non directly usable format data, you'll gain much speed.

Answer (score 1):

> Only need **speed**.

In my current project I have a very strange build setup.

I have currently like 100 config*.c files with a single exported structure. I use gcc compiler. The library looks along like this:

```
// config.h

struct config_s {
    char name[24];
    bool is_debug_enable;
    char some_data[24];
    char some_encryption_key[24];
    /* etc. */
}

const struct config_s *config_get(void);

// config.c  
const struct config_s *config_get(void) {
    extern const struct config_s _config_instatation;
    return &_config_instatation;
}
```

and example of those 100+ configuration files looks like this:

```
// config_kamil.c
#include <config.h>
const struct config_s _config_instatation = {
    .name = "kamil",
    .is_debug_enable = true,
    .some_data = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, },
    .some_encryption_key = { 0x20, 0x30, 0x40, },
};
```

The linker is invoked 100+ times *on each* of these config_*.c files and links it with the rest of codebase. The compilation takes a *long* time to link all these and build configuration is a mess. And I get over 100 executables. User chooses which configuration he wants to put on which device.

Alternatively I tried to make a `__attribute__((__section__("config")))` and put the `_config_instatation` into that section. After the .elf file is done, we could just substitute the section with `objcopy`. This was *fast* and there was only a single executable. That resulted in errors: compiler was smart enough to optimize dead code and it optimized a lot and the injected data were not always in the right format, a separate program/script was needed to be build for compiling the data. I went with the longer to compiler but easier and a bit safer approach.

You stated that the user gives the configuration. Depending on what you want (or rather: if your business plan is to charge the user if he wants to change the configuration or not) you can compile a static-set of configurations and give user only the executables, just like I do. User sees machine code only. If he wants to change the configuration, he has to pay for a new executable.

Alternatively you can setup a service, that will work like: user will post his configuration in a human/user readable format, and your service will transform this configuration into an object file with a parser and compiler and will link it with the rest of your codebase and return a executable to the user. I could imagine such service being download-able and install-able on users computer (with the compiler & and all the dependencies, etc.), but I could also imagine such service as a http-web-post based service.

Anyway the resulting data are embedded in the executable. So they can be parsed/preparsed/prepared in the most readable and parse-able format you want it to be, ready to be used. I don't think you will get faster then that. The drawback is that for each configuration you have to go through the compiler and for each configuration you get a separate executable.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of absolute speed, (de)serializing from a binary format is probably the fastest, but like @Bodo said in the comments, any difference in processing time between data encodings is likely to be infinitesimally small compared to the time taken for the actual I/O operation.

Incidentally, loading it as an .so is likely to be the slowest option. Also the least portable, in terms of the format of your data. Both your executable and your 'configuration' will become tied to your architecture, while in the other cases, at least your configuration file retains portability.

Since you say you are cross-compiling, it makes all the more sense to use a portable approach so that you can test the code on your host machine as well if required using the exact same data file.